# Comapring columns in 2 files and printing the values that differ

Tags: awk, grep, columns, join

I have a file (file-1) that looks like this,

```
DIP-10097N|refseq:NP_416170|uniprotkb:P30015
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177
DIP-10168N|refseq:NP_418766|uniprotkb:P15005
DIP-10199N|refseq:NP_415632|uniprotkb:P30958
DIP-10358N|refseq:NP_418659|uniprotkb:P28903
DIP-10440N|refseq:NP_289596|uniprotkb:P20082
DIP-10441N|refseq:NP_417502|uniprotkb:P20083
DIP-10441N|refseq:NP_417502|uniprotkb:P20083
DIP-10467N|refseq:NP_415423|uniprotkb:P09373
DIP-10469N|refseq:NP_418386|uniprotkb:P32674
DIP-10562N|refseq:NP_418370|uniprotkb:P17888
DIP-10582N|refseq:NP_414864|uniprotkb:P77743
DIP-10592N|refseq:NP_415819|uniprotkb:P37344
```

and another (file-2) which looks like this,

```
DIP-10331N|refseq:NP_311078|uniprotkb:P12638     DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177
DIP-10331N|refseq:NP_311078|uniprotkb:P12638    DIP-10840N|refseq:NP_414640|uniprotkb:P10408
DIP-1025N|refseq:NP_414574|uniprotkb:P00968     DIP-10097N|refseq:NP_416170|uniprotkb:P30015
DIP-10467N|refseq:NP_415423|uniprotkb:P09373    DIP-10097N|refseq:NP_416170|uniprotkb:P30015
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177    DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177    DIP-10750N|refseq:NP_289799|uniprotkb:P02410
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177    DIP-10757N|refseq:NP_288150|uniprotkb:P02421
```

In output I want to print the contents of file-1 plus the value in either column of file-2 that has the same value as that of file-1 in the other column. Like this,

```
DIP-10097N|refseq:NP_416170|uniprotkb:P30015 DIP-1025N|refseq:NP_414574|uniprotkb:P00968
DIP-10097N|refseq:NP_416170|uniprotkb:P30015 DIP-10467N|refseq:NP_415423|uniprotkb:P09373
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177 DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177 DIP-10750N|refseq:NP_289799|uniprotkb:P02410
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177    DIP-10757N|refseq:NP_288150|uniprotkb:P02421
DIP-10117N|refseq:NP_414973|uniprotkb:P08177 DIP-10331N|refseq:NP_311078|uniprotkb:P12638
DIP-10467N|refseq:NP_415423|uniprotkb:P09373 DIP-10097N|refseq:NP_416170|uniprotkb:P30015
```

Is there a way I can do it using awk or grep.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wide known operation in **awk** — collect array from key-file then use the array to operate with second file values

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
            A[$2] = A[$2] " " $1
            next
    }
    $1 in A{
            for(i=1;i<=split(A[$1], B);i++)
                print $1 B[i]
    }
    ' file2 file1
```

Or a little bit shorter:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
            A[$2] = A[$2] $2 " " $1 "\n"
            next
    }
    $1 in A{
            printf "%s", A[$1]
    }
    ' file2 file1
```

Other variant

```
grep -f <(cat -E file1) file2 |
sed 's/\(\S*\)\s*\(\S*\)/\2\t\1/' |
sort
```

At last easiest (as for me):

```
join -2 2 file1 <(sort -k2 file2)
```

Comment: Thanks. All of these work. Can you be so kind to explain the last code please.

Comment: To join files its should be sorted by join field. As we can see file1 is sorted already so we'l `sort file2` by second field(`-k2` option) only. Then we join two files by first field file1 (which have just 1) as default and file2 by second field(option `-2 2`). So output will be: field 1 from file1(which equal field 2 from file2) and residue — corespondent field 1 from file2